# How to use a click listener to increase the value of a variable within a model

Tags: javascript, angular

So basically I have a model that contains several different variables that are numbers. There are five different variables and I'd like to use one function to increase the corresponding stat based on which button was clicked by changing the data being passed within that button. Essentially I have five different buttons that look like this.

```
<h4>
<span>Str: {{currentCharacter.classStr}}</span>
<button (click) = "onStatIncrease()">+</button>
</h4>
```

classStr is one of the five variables within the model that I need to increase when the buton is pressed so what I need to do is figure out how to set my function up to know which variable to increase.

```
onStatIncrease(){
 <figure out which button was clicked and increase the corresponding variable accordingly>
}
```

I'm just not sure what data to pass or how to do that. Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: are you manually printing five variables or using `ngFor`?

Answer (score 0):

If I understand your problem, this can help you:

```
<h4>
    <span>Str: {{currentCharacter.classStr}}</span>
    <button (click) = "onStatIncrease('variable-1')">+</button>
</h4>


onStatIncrease(whichVariableToIncrease){
    switch(whichVariableToIncrease) {
        case 'variable-1':
            // Update the right variable.
            break;

        case '...':
            // ...
            break;
    }
}
```

UPDATE

Maybe this solution is better (didn't test it)

```
<button (click) = "onStatIncrease('classStr')">+</button>

...

onStatIncrease(whichVariableToIncrease) {

     this.currentCharacter[whichVariableToIncrease] += 1;
```

Comment: This worked for what I'm trying to do, thank you! Although it wasn't as efficient as I was hoping for. Is there not a way to do it without all the different cases? What I was trying to avoid was writing five different functions, and this is almost like doing just that. Essentially I have this.currentCharacter.classStr/classDex/classInt/classWis/classCon and i'd love to be able to have something in the function that sort of acts a place holder for which stat so I could have like
    onStatIncrease(passedStat){
    this.currentCharacter.passedStat += 1;
    }

Comment: Yeah I know, it's not the most elegant way.

Answer (score 0):

If all these buttons are nested under the same parent, you can create one event listener for all of them using [event delegation](https://davidwalsh.name/event-delegate). Even if they're not nested, you can still add the click listener on `document`.

e.g.

```
document.addEventListener('click', (e) => {
  if (e.target.matches('button')) {
    // increase the value of the current character
  }
})
```

You mentioned that there are 5 variables that you want to change. I'm not sure how the data is represented on the Angular side but you can pass in keys to the data attributes of the buttons to find which variable you need to change.

So your button could look like this:

```
<button data-id="classStr">+</button>
```

And you can get that attribute from the listener by doing:

```
e.target.dataset.id
```

Answer (score 0):

I assume you have aa array of objects

```
currentCharacter = [
    {key: 'classStr', value:1},
    {key: 'classDex', value:2},
    {key: 'classInt', value:3},
    {key: 'classWis', value:4},
    {key: 'assCon ', value:5}
  ];
```

You can make use of `*ngFOr` index

```
<div *ngFor="let item of currentCharacter; let i = index">
  <h4 >
      <span>Str: {{item.value}}</span>
      <button (click) = "onStatIncrease(i, item.value)">+</button>
  </h4>
</div>
```

and in your function pass index and value to update.

```
onStatIncrease(index, value){
    this.currentCharacter[index].value = value+1;
}
```